# Сложение списка словарей

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть два списка:

```py
list_one = [{"name": "Alex", "value": 1}, {"name": "Bob", "value": 2}]

list_two = [{"name": "Alex", "value": 1}, {"name": "Bob", "value": 2}]
```

Нужно их сложить так что бы получился третий такого вида:

```py
list_three = [{"name": "Alex", "value": 2}, {"name": "Bob", "value": 4}]
```

Первые два списка словарей всегда будут одинаковые по длине и словари будут отличатся только значением "value". То есть поле "name" первого словаря будет совпадать с полем "name" первого элемента второго словаря.
Через цикл не совсем корректно это делать, так как словарей в списке может быть до тысячи.

Comment: А почему вы думаете, что через цикл некорректно делать? Вполне рабочий вариант.

Comment: При большом количестве элементов это занимает много времени

Comment: Если мы говорим про тысячу элементов в списке - то это совсем не большое количество. Простой проход циклом с элементарными операциями над небольшими словарями даже для миллионов элементов занимает доли секунды. Если у вас на тысяче элементов работает долго, то вы что-то делаете неправильно. Если вы приведёте ваш вариант кода, мы сможем точно сказать, в чём проблема.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы, конечно, можете поизощряться с модулем `collections`, но мне кажется, что работа с табличным форматом будет и удобнее и быстрее:

```
import pandas as pd
list_one = [{"name": "Alex", "value": 1}, {"name": "Bob", "value": 2}]
list_two = [{"name": "Alex", "value": 1}, {"name": "Bob", "value": 2}]
res = pd.DataFrame(list_one+list_two).groupby("name", as_index=False).sum().to_dict("records")
print(res)
```

> [{'name': 'Alex', 'value': 2}, {'name': 'Bob', 'value': 4}]

**UPDATE**:

Если нужно складывать значения по модулю (абсолютные), то делаем так:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(list_one+list_two).groupby("name", as_index=False)["value"].apply(lambda x:x.abs().sum()).to_dict("records")
```

**UPDATE 2**:

Для вычитания можно сделать так (принимая во внимание, что списков всего два):

```
res = pd.DataFrame(list_one+list_two).groupby("name", as_index=False)["value"].apply(lambda x:x.iloc[0] - x.iloc[-1]).to_dict("records")
```

Comment: Можно ли вычитать из первого списка второй ? subtract не могу применить так как работаем по сути с DataFrameGroupBy

Comment: с суммой по модулю проблем нет - все решается через лямбду. а вот с вычитанием - тут вам нужно определяться, что из чего вычитать, и чего вы хотите достичь в конечном итоге.

Comment: Это мне помогло, спасибо